# Datagrid behavior differs on server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, datagrid

It may be impossible to answer this question, but maybe someone met this issue and can provide me some ideas. We are converting all of our apps to framework 4.0. We were on 2.0. On one of my asp app, I got a `DataGrid`. On this `DataGrid`, I have a `SelectedIndexChanged`. In this event, this line won't work on server, but will locally:

```
    myDataGrid.SelectedItem.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(253, 247, 166)
```

This is supposed to turn the line yellow. I use IIS, My system is windows 7, the server is windows server 2008. Any ideas? Need more information before being able to answer?

Update:
It seems that the `SelectedIndexChanged` won't even fire.